# How to install iPython (and then iPython Notebook)?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I currently have Python 3.3 installed on my laptop, and I am using Windows 7.

I am hitting a wall on installing iPython. I have watched two youtube videos and followed along, but I just don't have iPython, any help?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCjxkrs_INg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7u7kqotF-M

:(

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to install IPython on Windows is to install it as part of a Python distribution.

I've installed IPython for Python 3.3 with both methods shown in those videos, but have found the [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) distribution to be simpler to set up and use. The download for the 3.3 version is at http://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/files/WinPython_3.3/3.3.3.2/

WinPython includes IPython Notebook and qtconsole as well as all the dependencies for IPython.

It also includes a good lightweight IDE called Spyder that can use IPython as its interpreter.

Comment: Thanks Rynant, do you know WinPython also installs Pandas? My main reason of installing iPython is to be able to use the analytics packages like Pandas. I am really new to this so sorry if my question sounds funny :P

Comment: Yes, it installs pandas. The whole package list is here: http://sourceforge.net/p/winpython/wiki/PackageIndex_33/. You can also use pip (which is also included) to install additional packages.

Comment: I installed WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.2.exe but I didn't it been added to my start - launch program menu. Am I missing any steps? There is a folder however under my download folder named with WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.2.

Comment: @PerriMa When the WinPython installer is run, WinPython installs in the folder that you specify during the setup (you probably selected the download folder). When WinPython is first installed, it is portable (Windows settings are not touched); which is why it doesn't show in the start menu. I would move the 'WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.2' folder to where you want it to be, then run the 'WinPython Control Panel.exe' and click 'Register Distribution' in the Advanced menu.